# OpenId4Java - firing the servlet?

Tags: java, openid

I see these two OpenId4Java examples: [their site](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/wiki/SampleConsumer) and [the other one](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/openid4java/samples/consumerservlet/ConsumerServlet.java.html).

Can you tell me please what I should do apart of having this java class which is doing all the stuff? I suppose I have to set up the servlet in web.xml?

I'm trying to call this method from my Listener of the login button:

```
authRequest(String userSuppliedString,
        HttpServletRequest httpReq, HttpServletResponse httpResp)
```

but I receive a strange error when initializing the ConsumerManager in constructor:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery
```

Do you know what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found the answer. I just have to define a servlet for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing library openid4java, which you can download from their website.

That library has other dependencies which is included in the ZIP file you download in the /lib directory (dependencies being apache-commons, guice, etc.).

The example you found is beneficial to other readers since official openid4java documentation is pretty unclear, so it is worth mentioning here:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/openid4java/samples/consumerservlet/ConsumerServlet.java.html